# how to change textView repeatedly after pressing on a button until specific case

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a layout that has a textView that has a number, an editText that has a hint for the entered item and a button, and when i press on the button i'll get the entered text and put it inside a variable and then decrease the number that is inside the text view until it is 0

here's the piece of my code:

```
            job = "";
            adjective = "";

            this.changeMyEditText(2, "job");
            job = this.getMyText();

            this.changeMyEditText(1, "adjective");
            adjective = this.getMyText();

            scan.close();
```

and here's the changeMyEditText function:

```
public void changeMyEditText(int num, String type) {
    TextView numOfEnteredWords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numOfEnteredWords);
    EditText enteredWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredWord);


    numOfEnteredWords.setText(num + " word(s) left");
    enteredWord.setHint(type);
}
```

and the getMyText method:

```
public String getMyText() {
    EditText enteredWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredWord);
    return enteredWord.getText().toString();


}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

On button's click listener event, you can decrease textViewNumber -1.

and can check on every button's click if number = 0 then do whatever you want to do.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (textViewNumber != 0) {
                    textViewNumber--; //I guess if you want to change number by -1
                } else {
                    // Your action on textviewNumber become 0
                }
            }
        });
```